# How to convert codebase to a hard-to-rip version?

Tags: image, codebase

For a job interview I have to hand them some code I wrote to determine my object oriented programming skills.

Now have I been working for about two years at the same company and we have a project which I copied. But I can't just send them this project because of the copyright. But I do want to show it to them because I need that job.

Is there any way (legal) to show them the project? Can I just rip a few files out which I wrote? Could I convert the project to jpg or something. Yeah they can OCR it but I don't think they will do it.

Can anybody help please?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents worth - but if the project belongs to the company you currently work for then I would avoid any use at all of this codebase outside of the company without their express permission. Even if the company your interviewing for has no intention of copying the code you provide, it will still have a bearing on how trustworthy they see you as.. Even in the code you provide them with demonstrates remarkable coding skills, they may be unlikely to employ you if the feel that you might hand part of their codebase on to another company under similar circumstances..